# SNMP Set:Timeout, No Response

Tags: snmp

```
  snmpwalk -v1 -c public $ip enterprises.10642.20.10.10.5.11.3.0;

  snmpget -v1 -c public $ip enterprises.10642.20.10.10.5.11.4.0;

  snmpset -v1 -c public $ip enterprises.10642.20.10.10.5.11.4.0 s 1664 ;
```

the snmpset was working with me fine before changed the community name from "public" to "loreal" 
after the change the snmpget is respond but the snmpset not respond >>>

```
C:\>snmpGet -v1 -c loreal $ip 1.3.6.1.4.1.10642.20.10.10.5.11.4.0
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.10642.20.10.10.5.11.4.0 = STRING: "********"

C:\>snmpSet -v1 -c loreal $ip 1.3.6.1.4.1.10642.20.10.10.5.11.4.0 s 1664
Timeout: No Response from 10.84.10.85
```

SO anybody have an idea!!

Comment: Obvious question: Did you actually change the community string on the target device?

Comment: YES OF COURSE

I changed with zpl command , this command line special for zebra printer

Comment: The read community string is working, which suggests there is a separate one for write.  Have you tried the `snmpset` with the old string?

Comment: @Paul YOU have right the problem was in the ZPL command , I edited the command line and it's work now. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change `CommunityName` in `ZEPRA` printer by sending the commands `ZPLII`.

for more information:
  [ZPL II Programming Guide](https://www.servopack.de/support/zebra/ZPLII-Prog.pdf)

Description ^NN command: Use this command to set the Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP)
parameters.
Format ^NNa,b,c,d,e,f

EX:

```
 ^XA

 ^NN,,,test,test,test

 ^XZ
```

We can change it with [SGD commands](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/knowledge-articles/kr403-zpl-and-sgd-commands.html)

```
! U1 setvar "ip.snmp.get_community_name" "TEST"

! U1 setvar "ip.snmp.set_community_name" "TEST"
```