# How to change the SNMP community name "public" in (ZT230) Zebra printer?

Tags: windows-10, snmp, zebra-printer

I have an [SNMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol) issue with the community name.

The default name is "public". When I tried to change it to anther one, I find that I can *walk* the SNMP with two name "public" and "loreal" (giving the command `snmpwalk`) without apparent errors, like in lines below :

```
C:\>snmpwalk -v1 -c LOREAL 128.86.201.207 enterprises.683.3.3.0
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.683.3.3.0 = STRING: "LOREAL"

C:\>snmpwalk -v1 -c public 128.86.201.207 enterprises.683.3.3.0
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.683.3.3.0 = STRING: "LOREAL"
```

But when I use the command `snmpSET`, I can't use the new name ("LOREAL") to change value

```
C:\>snmpset -v1 -c LOREAL 128.86.201.207 enterprises.683.3.3.0 s SWAT
Timeout: No Response from 128.86.201.207

C:\>snmpset -v1 -c public 128.86.201.207 enterprises.683.3.3.0 s SWAT
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.683.3.3.0 = STRING: "SWAT"
```

Why this happens, how can I definitively change or delete the *"public"* and use only "LOREAL" for the [snmpset/get commands](https://linux.die.net/man/1/snmpcmd)?

**Notes:**

- the MIB tree for [zebra printer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebra_Technologies).
- I change the community Name with [ZPL II commands](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/software/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf)
- My OS is win10

Comment: Add the version of the OS and of the SNMP. You can always [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1252767/edit) your own post. What do you mean _"I figer that I can walk"_?

Comment: Check if the edit make it more clear and [edit] it again adding the operations you have done to set/change the new name, making more clear the Note... good luck.

Comment: I always have the same problem with language i need improve my English before posting here, thanks

Comment: Add some tags as the windows version for the OS... some one may filter the question through the tags. BTW the bigger part of the users here has to translate in English question and answers. `:-)` Try. Continue to try. Use wordreference, collins google or  whatever... and good luck.

Comment: You are welcome. Add your OS version... NOW ! :-) If it was Linux you should had found interesting the page ["How to change the default value for the SNMP community string "](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-to-change-the-default-value-for-the-snmp-community-string-4175545429/). They suggested to change the value by hands in the `snmpd.conf` file and restarting the daemon... So you can start to see the configuration file under your OS. [Here](https://support.managed.com/kb/a764/how-to-install-snmp-and-configure-the-community-string-for-windows.aspx) for windows.

Comment: What is the significance of the word `LOREAL`?

Comment: @Ramhound `LOREAL` is just example what I'm try to do is changing the pincode for this printer  by set value from 4 number , but when I changed the community name ,I had this problem

Comment: @yazan What do you mean with the 1st note? Exactly which command did you used to change the name? I added the tag windows 10...Give it a check to the 2 links on the previous comment. The second is for windows... search for the configuration file under windows and see inside the file (it should be a text file that you can open with notepad - do not modify it until you know what you are doing and how to restore the original one)

Comment: @Hastur  I have 100 zebra printer , I changed the community name correctly on all of them, just three printer gave me this error and if you want see the commande just see to this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1248252/snmp-get-timeout-no-response)

Comment: If they are the same model of the other 97 ones, why don't you try to reset them, restoring the original settings, and try again to change the name...

Comment: @Hastur I tried that but it didn't  work

Comment: Hi all ,
I found solution, my problem was with the version firmware for this printers.
the model of printers is `ZT230-200dpi ZPL` and the version of firmware was `V72.19.1Z`,
so when I try to change community Name with `zpl commands` , the commands were execute incorrectly.
I did upgrade the firmware to `V72.20.1Z` and I tried to send `zpl commands`,
now I have response from `SNMP get/set` and I can change the values with the chosen community Name

Comment: @yazan Post it as answer of your own question... and let me know. I will be ready to upvote it. (if not after some time those informations will be deleted...)

Comment: @Hastur I can't write answer , I'm banned :(

Comment: Banned?? Why? What have you done to be banned? `:-)`. If you want I can add the answer for you... but I think it is better if you wait the end of the ban and you do it yourself. BTW it doesn't seem to me that, _at present_, you are banned...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution, my problem was with the version firmware for this printers.

the model of printers is `ZT230-200dpi ZPL` and the version of firmware was `V72.19.1Z`, so when I try to change community Name with `zpl commands` , the commands were execute incorrectly.

I did upgrade the firmware to `V72.20.1Z` and I tried to send `zpl commands`, now I have response from `SNMP get/set` and I can change the values with the chosen community Name